# Is there a way I can restrict the height of an image in a jumbotron to the height of the jumbotron?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm not sure if the question was clear enough, maybe looking at the website might help.

http://settlecars.com

I want the image of the three cars on the right to stay <strike>inside of</strike> the same height as the jumbotron when the screen is resized (or when viewing on smaller screen devices, e.g: smart phones). How can I do this?

Currently, this is the html I have in place for that section of the website:

```
<div class="jumbotron text-left">
  <h1>Liverpool Vehicle Hire</h1> 
  <p>The one stop shop for all your private hire needs <br> in the Sefton &amp; Liverpool areas.</p>
  <img src="header.png" height="357px" align="right" style="position:absolute; top: 30px; right:0px; z-index:0">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to set a `overflow:hidden;` property on your `.jumbotron` element.

Due to the fact that your car images are using `position:absolute;`, you would have to also give the `.jumbotron` element a `position:relative;` to anchor the image.

Simply add this to your CSS:

```
.jumbotron {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
```

**edit**

When I tested this using firebug on your site it worked perfectly fine, but if you still want to tweak it after this, you can add the following:

```
.jumbotron > img {
  height:100%;
}
```

Thanks to the `position:relative;` anchoring the image this will force the image height into the `.jumbotron` height.

Comment: Hi Frits!

Thanks for such a quick reply. I'll try that out now!

Comment: Sure thing. I added an edit with an extra optional tweak in case you needed it.

Comment: Would that force the img to always fill the height of the jumbotron? If so, that would probably be a lot better.

Comment: Yes, but only if you've given the `.jumbotron` a `position:relative;`, the overflow is more of a safety net in this instance :)

Comment: Thanks! I've just done that. Just waiting on the company to get back to us with their logo and then I can sign that site off as complete!

Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: Nice answer. be sure to upvote the question aswell ;-)